# Quick Select creating partition issue

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

So in order to get a quick select actually working I have a bit of an issue with creating the 3 necessary partitions of the original array. the custom data type is basically just a manual vector creation.

```
public T MinExtended(T[] data, int k)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    T pivot = data[rnd.Next(0, data.Length - 1)];
    if (data.Length == 1)
        return data[0];

    T[] Less = new T[data.Length];
    T[] Greater = new T[data.Length];
    T[] Equal = new T[data.Length];

    int less = 0;
    int greater = 0;
    int equal = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (data[i].CompareTo(pivot) == -1)
        {
            Less[less] = data[i];
            less++;
        }

        if (data[i].CompareTo(pivot) == 1)
        {
            Greater[greater] = data[i];
            greater++;
        }

        if (data[i].CompareTo(pivot) == 0)
        {
            Equal[equal] = data[i];
            equal++;
        }
    }

    if (Less.Length.CompareTo(k) >= 0)
        return MinExtended(Less, k);

    if ((Less.Length + Equal.Length).CompareTo(k) >= 0)
        return pivot;

    else
        return MinExtended(Greater, k - Less.Length - Equal.Length);
}
```

This of course returns a

> stack overflow error.

I'm not entirely sure why or how to fix it though

Comment: This is because of `tail-recursion`. You are just going too deep. Replace recursion with `while-loop`.

Comment: not sure how to implement that. what am I changing?